# Adjectives for seasons

Tags: word-choice, seasons

I recently encountered:

vernal adj. of, in, or appropriate to spring

And I truly wonder if there is also equivalents for the other seasons (summer, autumn, and winter).

EDIT:

I just found aestival n. relating to summer.

Please feel free to contribute words that have the similar/same meaning to spring and summer even though I have found those.

Comment: Well, there is *autumnal*. And *wintery*.

Comment: There is *wintry* and [*hibernal*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hibernal).

Comment: _Vernal_ and _Autumnal_ both have a named _Equinox_ (Lat pl _Equinoctes_, English pl _Equinoxes_), but _Hibernal_ and _(A)Estival_ don't seem to have attached to the Solstices. Perhaps that's because the plural of _solstice_ is just _solstices_, regular as clockwork.

Comment: Hibernating critters and estivating critters need never meet. :)

Comment: What about "spicy"?  Covers all the seasons, doesn't it?

Comment: Another adjective for winter is "brumal".

Comment: You can use *wintertime* as a noun adjunct, as in "Wintertime Love" by Doors, as well as *summertime*, *springtime*..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complement the other suggestions:

Summer: summery, pre-summery (ex. hot "summery temperatures"), summerly (that works as adv. and adj.) //
Spring: spring-like/springlike, pre-springlike //
winter: brumal (literary) //
autumn: autumn-like //